# VIM deleting columns and merging lines

Tags: vim

I have a file that is formatted like this:

```
A    abc
A    123
A    1g5
A    4Ct
B    abc
B    123
B    4Ct
```

I would like to remove all but the first replicated things in col 1 and merge everything that is in col 2 into one line. Like this:

```
A    abc,123,1g5,4Ct
B    abc,123,4Ct
```

I have been using a combination of search and replace for the info in col1 and replacing it with a comma and gJ to merge lines. My file is fairly long so this is a very tedious process. Is there another way to do this but faster? Thanks for any advice

Comment: Welcome to SO! vim is an editor. A powerful one, but just and editor. Another way to do it faster is to use python for text files processing.

Comment: @TarekDakhran what would be the python to do that?

Comment: While still manual, this should be pretty fast if done at the keyboard.  I would "j" join all the lines as appropriate and then s/ [A-Z] /,/g to get rid of the first columns.

Comment: For example like [this](https://pastebin.com/2kd5ZmvC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression using a zero-width look-behind to match a sequence of lines starting with the first word.

Then you can use that to replace the newline (joining the lines) and the first word, substituting them for a comma.

This command does that all:

```
:%s/\v(^(\S+).*)@<=\n\2\s+/,/
```

Breaking this down:

- `%s/.../.../`: Substitute on every line.
- [`\v`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv): Use "verymagic" regular expressions, so we don't have to backslash most metacharacters.
- `(...)`[`@<=`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D): Use a zero-width look-behind to search for the initial line, but not make it part of the match. Inside that:
- `^(\S+).*`: Match a word (sequence of one or more non-blank characters) at the beginning of the line, save it in group `\2`, and use `.*` to consume the rest of the line.
- [`\n`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cn): Match a line-break. Replacing it will allow us to join the lines.
- `\2`: Match group 2 again. This ensures we're handling subsequent lines starting with the same sequence.
- `\s+`: First, make sure group 2 is followed by whitespace (to avoid matching a prefix.) Also, consume whitespace until the second field of the line.
- `,`: Replace the part outside of the look-behind (`\n\2\s+`) with a single comma.

The result matches your expectation exactly for your given input.